# How can I extract several sets of pixel coordinates (u, v) from an image and store them in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

For example, if I were to use the following code for a photo in my MATLAB path:

```
imtool('Vision.bmp')
```

the following figure would load:
[MATLAB Image with Pixel Coordinates in Bottom Left Corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq45s.png)

Based on where I hover my mouse on this image, the pixel coordinates in the bottom left corner change. I want to be able to extract the coordinates from this image and store them in a matrix, so that later on I can extract the same data - from the image I specified - using this newly created matrix.

Fair warning, I've just started to learn to code.

Comment: You likely want to use something like [`ginput`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wolfie ginput worked great... extremely late response